# Is there a way for ah HTML List Item reference another and automatically use that LI's assigned number?

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm creating this massive List for a client's Terms & Conditions.  It is essentially one massive List Item with two or 3 sub-list items.

Since number is automatic with OLs, is there a way for an LI to refer to another LI by it's assigned number?

i.e.

```
1 Item A
2 Item B
  2.1 See "1"
```

Where "1" is simply a pointer and not a hard-coded text reference, thus if 1 changes the pointer changes.

Thus:

```
1 Item Z
2 Item A
3 Item B
  3.1 See "2"
```

To clarify, I mean the # at the beginning.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a summarized listing of the HTML that you have.

Comment: Just your basic LI elements.  Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

OLs are arrays, you could easily get the container and then get the nth `<li>` element using the `:nth-of-type` selector.

```
var getLi = function (listId, index) {
    return $("#" + listId).find("li:nth-of-type(" + index + ")");
};
```

You can see a more fleshed-out result in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daiopowen/fwuog3rt/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the response Steve.  I am really trying as hard as possible to keep away from editing anything other than CSS/html.  The simpler I can keep the sites, the better for now.  Will keep your suggestion in mind for sure though.